# problem automatic log off when I navigate between tabs (Firebase Auth rest API)

Tags: flutter, rest, http, authentication, firebase-authentication

Hi I'm building an app and I'm using authentication using Firebase Auth rest API but the problem is that when I navigate between my tabs my app logOut automatically I don't  know if it's expiration of token problem or something else so can some one help with that?

this is my auth part it's in my provider package

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
   String _token;
   String _userId; 
   bool get isAuth {
      return token != null;
   }  
   String get token{
          return _token;
        }
   String get userId {
     return _userId;
   }  
   Future<void> signup(String email, String password) async {
     final url = Uri.parse(
       'https://...myurl...'
       );
     try {
       final response = await http.post(url,body: json.encode(
            {
           'email': email,
           'password':password,
           'returnSecureToken': true,
           },), );
        final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        if(responseData['error'] != null){
          throw Exception();
        }
        _token = responseData['idToken'];
        _userId = responseData['localId'];
    notifyListeners();
     }  catch (error) {
         throw error;
     } }
   Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
     final url = Uri.parse( 'https://...myurl...' );
     try {
       final response = await http.post(
           url, 
           body: json.encode(
            {
           'email': email,
           'password':password,
           'returnSecureToken': true,
           },),);
     }  catch (error) {
         throw error;
     } }}
```

this is the Ath screen:

```
enum AuthMode { Signup, Login }

class AuthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/auth';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    bool _isLoading= false;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent[100],
      body: SizedBox(
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
           Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),


              child: Expanded(
                child: 
                SizedBox(
                  height: 280,
                                 ),
              ),
            ), 

            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                height: deviceSize.height,
                width: deviceSize.width,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[

                SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                child: LogoBekery(
                  color1:Colors.white,
                  color2:Colors.white,
                  color3:Colors.white,
                  ),
      ),
                    
                 SizedBox(
                  child:  ImageSlideshow(
                   isLoop: true,
                    width: double.infinity,
              
                    height: 250,
              
                    initialPage: 0,
              
                    indicatorColor: Colors.pink,
              
                    indicatorBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              
                    children: [
                         
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/logoA.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/logoB.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/logoC.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/logoD.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ],
              
                    onPageChanged: (value) {
                     // print('Page changed: $value');
                    },
              
                    autoPlayInterval: 3000,
                  ),
      ),
                    
                    Flexible(
                      flex: deviceSize.width > 600 ? 2 : 1,
                    child: AuthCard(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _submitAuthForm(
    String email,
    String password,
    String username,
    bool isLogin,
    BuildContext ctx,
  ) 
  async {
    UserCredential authResult;  }
}

class AuthCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthCard({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthCardState createState() => _AuthCardState();
}

class _AuthCardState extends State<AuthCard> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  AuthMode _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
  Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
  };
  var _isLoading = false;
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _submit() async{
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // Invalid!
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
  
    try {
      if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
         await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).login(
          _authData['email'] ,
          _authData['password'] );
        
        } else {
         
       await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signup(
          _authData['email'] ,
          _authData['password'] );
      }
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(ProductOverviewScreen.routeName);
    } on Exception catch (error) {
        var errorMsg = 'Authentification Failed!';
     }catch (error){
        var errorMsg = 'Could not authentificate! please try later...';

     }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _switchAuthMode() {
    if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.Signup;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 8.0,
      child: Container(
        height: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 320 : 260,
        constraints:
            BoxConstraints(minHeight: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 150 : 260),
        width: deviceSize.width * 0.8,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (!RegExp(r'\S+@\S+\.\S+').hasMatch(value)) {
                      return 'Invalid email!';
                    }
                    return null;
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['email'] = value;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                      return 'Password is too short!';
                    }
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['password'] = value;
                  },
                ),
                if (_authMode == AuthMode.Signup)
                  TextFormField(
                    enabled: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup
                        ? (value) {
                            if (value != _passwordController.text) {
                              return 'Passwords do not match!';
                            }
                          }
                        : null,
                  ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                if (_isLoading)
                  CircularProgressIndicator()
                else
                  RaisedButton(
                    child:
                        Text(_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP'),
                    onPressed: _submit,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button.color,
                  ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                      '${_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'SIGNUP' : 'LOGIN'}'),
                  onPressed: _switchAuthMode,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4),
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Auth state is persisted automatically, so likely there's some problem in how you detect the current user. But without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'll be hard to help.

Comment: I've added the auth part of my code

Comment: How do you check if a user is loggedIn?

Comment: @PeterO.  in short term is use this mth
    try { if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
         await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).login( _authData['email'] ,  _authData['password'] );   } else {         
 await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signup( _authData['email'] , _authData['password'] );}      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(ProductOverviewScreen.routeName);
    } on Exception catch (error) {
 var errorMsg = 'Failed!';
 }catch (error){ var errorMsg = 'error'; }

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: @PeterO. I added my Auth screen on the post

Answer (score 0):

Your `_token` and `_userId` is only set after registering. You don't set it after loging in. Therefore token could be null and `isAuth` will return false.

I think you should set the value of `_token` and `_userId` after the login function.

```
Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
  final url = Uri.parse('https://...myurl...');
  try {
    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: json.encode(
        {
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
          'returnSecureToken': true,
        },
      ),
    );
    // added from here
    final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
    if (responseData['error'] != null) {
      throw Exception();
    }
    _token = responseData['idToken'];
    _userId = responseData['localId'];
    // to here.
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: should I take it off from signup or just add it on login as well?

Comment: Add it to login. The code I shared is an example. try that.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: I not sure but I think that I have a pb with my token it expire so may be the p is form firebase not in flutter but don't know how to handle that